# jQuery: noConflict bugging Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Hello Stackers,**

To get long things short, A Few months ago I've asked a question about a jQuery script, and that's fixed and working: A fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nryvvL9s/). However, I need the noConflict function, otherwise the script will crash other scripts.

I Follow the guide on the jQuery site, and this is my result;

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").hide();
    $("#div3").hide(); 
    $("#div4").hide();
    $("#div5").hide();

   $("#pick_go").click(function() {
        var openId = $("#pick_select").val();

        $("#div1").hide();
        $("#div2").hide();
        $("#div3").hide(); 
        $("#div4").hide();
        $("#div5").hide();

        $("#div" + openId).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

This, however, will break the Script, even on jsFiddle. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Break how? Do you get any error? or the script does nothing? Please be clear with your question.

Comment: No, you don't get any error. The DIVS aren't hidden anymore, and that's exactly what it should do. It should only show the selected DIV in te Input field.

Comment: okay. try doing a `jQuery.noConflict()` instead of `$.noConflict()`

Comment: There has to be errors if that code is being run after `$.noConflict()` because you are using `$`. Try changing to `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` so `$` is available the way you are using it

Comment: @charlietfl I'm sorry, but I don't really get it. I've got a fiddle for you, which will show the problem; [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fyatgxd1/)

Comment: right...look at the error thrown in browser dev tools console `$ is undefined`. You didn't include jQuery in demo... see this fix https://jsfiddle.net/fyatgxd1/1/

Comment: Thanks, however on the site, jQuery is included. It just says, `Uncaught TypeError: $.noConflict is not a function`

Comment: Problem Fixed. Thanks.